# Inconsistency in cross-validation results

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, discriminant-analysis

I have a set of dataset recorded from subjects as they perform some particular cognitive task. The data consists of 16 channels and a number of sample points per channel and I want to classify this data according to the cognitive task being performed (everything is labelled).

The issue is that I do not have a large amount of data (approximately 60 trials per session, 30 for each cognitive task) and I have 2 sessions. I am trying to train a Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) classifier to classify this data. The classifier is later to be used in **real-time** to give some form of output every number of samples.

I made use of a 5-fold cross-validation to measure the generalization error of my classifier. The problem is that when I run this 5-fold cross validation a number of times, the results I get are not constant at all. Instead there's a significant variation in the overall accuracy (for example, first 5-fold cross validation may yield an average accuracy of 80%, 2nd yields an accuracy of 65%, 3rd yields an average of 72% etc...). Is this normal? If not, what could be the causes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have discovered the fact that LDA models can suffer from *instability*: slight changes in the training set lead to very different models.

There's a whole body of literature on the variance of resampling methods for validation. This may give you a good start.

See also [here for a related discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/31507/4598).
(I'm sure there is a literature list somewhere around here, but I cannot find it right now)

Anyways,

- Braga-Neto has been working a lot on this
- There's a very nice technical report by Ron Kohavi
- We also did a study about [Variance reduction in estimating classification error using sparse datasets](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169743905000687)
- And another one on [Assessing and improving the stability of chemometric models in small sample size situations](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00216-007-1818-6)

Comment: would using some form of regularization scheme for the LDA diminish this problem?

Comment: @user2036690: possibly, yes. Still I recommend that you check first whether instability is really the problem, and after regularization check that things actually improve. *If* the problem is instability and your regularization is successful, you should also see an increase in hit rate.