# Issues with sequential feature selection

Tags: svm, matlab, feature-selection

I am trying to do some feature selection in gene expression data with 22215 features. I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/selecting-features-for-classifying-high-dimensional-data.html).

I initially applied filter method(ttest) to select the features having the best p values. I selected 100 features from them initially. Then I tried to apply sequential feature selection method on them with SVM classifier. However, when I do

```
[fs1, history] = sequentialfs(@SVM_class_fun, reducedL, yS1, 'cv', c);
```

it always returned me the 1st feature only. I mean in fs1 every other feature except the first one is 0. If I try to force it to give me 10 features with

```
[fs1, history] = sequentialfs(@SVM_class_fun, reducedL, yS1, 'cv', c, 'nfeatures', 10);
```

Here is my SVM_class_fun

```
function err = SVM_class_fun(xTrain, yTrain, xTest, yTest)
  model = svmtrain(xTrain, yTrain, 'Kernel_Function', 'rbf', 'boxconstraint', 10);
  err = sum(svmclassify(model, xTest) ~= yTest);
end
```

it will give me the first 10 selected by the filter method having lowest p values.

So this mean using sequentialfs is not helpful in this case.

To let you know I have just 12 examples. So my data matrix is of dimension 12x22215. Might this be the issue?

Can anyone provide some insights?

Comment: The fact that you are using a boxconstraint value of 10 is probably causing an issue. Try a value of 1. Otherwise your code seems fine. Wrapper feature selection on such a wide data set is always going to be difficult.

Comment: Also doing feature selection on the whole data set prior to classification can heavily bias results. See similar question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27750/feature-selection-and-cross-validation?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with the ordering of `xTrain`, `yTrain`, ... called by `sequentialfs`. It is acually `xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest`. Doing so fixed my problems.