# Correlation based feature selection with cross-validation

Tags: correlation, cross-validation, feature-selection

I am trying to do a correlation based feature selection for a classification model. Dataset details is given below.

Training :- 38 Samples, 7130 features. represented as **T**

Testing :- 34 Samples, 7130 features. represented as **S**

Target: 2 classes (Yes | No )

So, I need to select first 100 features highly correlated with class variable.

Here I have mentioned different approaches that I've tried, but I am not sure which approach is best. Please go through approaches given below and comment the best one.

1) Combined **T** and **S** to single table **X** = **T** + **S**. Let **{A}** be set of all features and **a** is an element of **{A}**. I calculated correlation of all **a** and then selected top 100 features to create a new dataset with dimension **72x100**

2) I applied correlation selection on **T**. The selected features will be extracted from **S**. We get new datasets **T`** and **S`**

But, I am not sure how to do cross validation in this procedure? Please help.

Comment: Your question seem to be similar to this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27750 . It seems that feature selection need to by approach 2 and it need to repeated for each fold of cross validation. See this answer for a demo (MATLAB) code: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/27751/156469

Comment: This is not correlation based, but. Another approach might be to use lasso.  Regularized regression is meant to handle the $ 'n<p'$ issue.  Lasso will in fact set some (most?) of the regression coefficients to zero.  The glmnet package will do this.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have to small sample size and to much features. 34+38=72 sample is to small for training classifier. Visual exporation of data is the best for your case.

Comment: Don't think visual exploration will be reliable either.  Related to split-sample validation, the sample size is too small by a factor of about 200 for split-sample methods to be stable.