Is it valid to exhaustively test all possible combinations of features to find the best combination?
I have about 1000 labelled observations from about 50 subjects responding physiologically under different situations and am trying to classify the situation (usually into three classes of roughly equal frequency but sometimes four or five classes). For each observation, I generate about 2000 features and need to select the best subset of features for classification. Using mRMR (minimal redundancy maximal relevance), I can reduce the features to about 25-100 features to start with before the mRMR scores drop very low (depending upon which classes I include).
I'm taking the first 20 of these (to keep numbers feasible) and testing all possible combinations of up to 8 features, giving about 264,000 combinations, using leave one subject out cross-validation. I then select the combination that gives the best accuracy. For LDA this only takes my laptop 6 hours, but I am also testing other classifiers which take longer (such as Gaussian SVM, having converted the five classes into ten binary classifiers, or three classes into three binary classifiers).
My question is whether this is a valid approach or if I am introducing bias, overfitting, etc., and if so, how to compensate for that. I've read that it is better to do feature selection within each fold, but I'm not even sure how I could do that, especially with leave one subject out.
I find that using mRMR alone is not suitable: if I just use the first 8 features from mRMR, I get a substantially lower accuracy than by finding the best combination. In one extreme case, with Gaussian SVM comparing just two classes, the difference was 99% accuracy versus 50%, but often it is about 10-20% difference in accuracy.)
I have two goals: 1) to select the best features to train a model on all the data and use this for classifying new observations, and 2) to estimate the accuracy of such a model for future observations.
Is there a way I can take into account the effect on accuracy, and is there a better way to select features if I am willing allocate this amount of calculation?
And while I'm asking, would it maybe make more sense to use PCA to create 5-10 components instead of using features directly?
Any advice appreciated! Many thanks.
More info (as requested):
To prevent an X-Y problem, maybe I should step back and also ask: What is the right/best/sensible approach to choosing features in my situation? I'm exploring different classification techniques, but right now I'm breaking a five class problem down into ten binary Gaussian SVM classifiers. For each classifier I'm trying to select the best features to use for those specific classes. If I simply use the first features as scored my mRMR, I get lower results. In terms of "valid", my approach gives me substantially better accuracies but are they just artificially higher? Or is this an approach that is recognised to be a bad idea? I also need to predict the classification accuracy for unseen data. Some pairs of responses are easy to classify, e.g. 98% accuracy, whilst one pair only manages 70% accuracy, with overall accuracy reaching about 60% (after summing the posterior probability scores for the ten classifiers and choosing the response with the highest score).
After selecting the eight features (or sometimes just six to train four times faster), I have tried SVM hyperparameter optimisation (kernel scale and box constraint) but I found it was best to use "1" for both of them, which also makes me think I may be selecting the best features for those values of kernel scale and box constraint, but adding testing different kernel scales and box constraints into the loop will give me many more combinations to test.
Why do I want to reduce the number of features?:
I get worse results if I include all the features or if I use only the first 8 or 20, etc., features as scored by mRMR. I want to avoid overfitting, and I've been told that with only 50 subjects, the number should be closer to 5-10 rather than 2000. I want a simpler and more explainable model, and, for research purposes, I wish to identify which features are most important.

Is this just a binary classification, and what sort of model are you using for this?

„would it maybe make more sense to use PCA to create 5-10 components instead of using features directly?“ Those PCA components rely on all of the features and do not reduce the number of features that are being used. What is your point behind reducing the number of features? If you do not need to reduce the features, but instead want to introduce some bias to reduce the variance, then you can think of incorporating some way of regularisation in your machine learning problem.

"I've read that it is better to do feature selection within each fold" where did you read that?

It is likely that all you will achieve is over-fitting the feature selection criterion and end up with a model that performs badly in operational use.

@SextusEmpiricus  I suspect that is to get an unbiased performance estimator that includes the effects of the variance due to the feature selection (usually this is nested cross-validation where the inner cross-validation is used to select the features and the outer to get an unbiased performance estimate.  There is practical demonstration of why this is necessary in my answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27750/feature-selection-and-cross-validation/27751#27751

I'd read about elastic net regression

@DikranMarsupial a test set in addition to training set and validation set will give a valid estimate for the performance. But I am not sure whether this is the issue of validity addressed here.

It is important to ask why you want to select the best set of features?  If it is just to improve operational performance, then you are better off using regularisation instead (as suggested by @LuIY) it is much less prone to overfitting.  There is a monograph on feature selection by Millar and hidden away in the appendices you can find exactly that advice!

@SextusEmpiricus Indeed it will, but the task here involves a relatively small amount of independent data, so both the validation and test estimates will have a high variance.  The first will lead to overfitting in feature selection, the second to unreliable performance estimation.  In this case I suspect nested cross-validation is likley to be better if you can afford the computational expense.  Note for many models you can get the inner cross-validation for free (e.g. Allen's PRESS statistic)

@DikranMarsupial I believe that we agree. What I am puzzled about is the formulation of the question "My question is whether this is a valid approach or if I am introducing bias, overfitting, etc". Certainly there can be overfitting and other methods might be better. But the question is whether the method is 'valid'. What this 'valid' means is not very clear.

@SextusEmpiricus yes, it is "valid" in the sense that it isn't breaking any "statistical laws", but that doesn't mean it isn't a very bad idea!

Thanks a lot for taking the time. To prevent an X-Y problem, maybe I should step back and ask: What is the right/best/sensible approach to choosing features in my situation? I've added more info at the end of my original question.

@user1596274 "Why do I want to reduce the number of features?: I get worse results if I include all the features..." - in that case use regularisation and keep all of the features (e.g. ridge regression/ridge logistic regression) or elastic net etc. to get a model that generalises well, use elastic net or L1 regularised logistiic regression to identify the features.  Much less prone to overfitting than conventional feature selection (especially exhaustive FS - which more or less guarantees overfitting the selection criterion)

@DikranMarsupial, regarding overfitting, I'm reducing the number of features in the model, so are you saying I'm actually increasing overfitting by reducing the number of features?

@DikranMarsupial, Regarding feature selection within the loop, I can understand how including all the subjects could give a noticeable difference in accuracy for 5-fold CV, but if I use leave-one-subject-out (LOSO) CV (with 50 subjects) for feature selection, surely the difference in accuracy will be almost negligible, and the difference in feature selection almost negligible too? Taken to the extreme, I could have 50 sets of test data each from only one subject & do CV with the remaining 49 in each case, then average the results, but would this not be almost identical to LOSO?

@user1596274 The point is that you can overfit the feature selection criterion rather than overfit the training data.  There is a very good paper on this by Ambroise and MacLachlan (doi: 10.1073/pnas.102102699).  LOOCV (and LOSO) will be approximately unbiased, but it is the variance of the estimator that allow over-fitting - these things were long neglected, but if evaluated correctly they can make a very large difference.  Note the book on feature selection I mentioned recommended not to do feature selection for performance reasons (because of this form of overfitting)


Is it valid to exhaustively test all possible combinations of features to find the best combination?

NO
The caveat is that what you propose is sort of valid (kinda, sorta, not really but maybe). However, it is ridiculous. To see why, assume you have only $200$ features. The possible features to select are ${200\choose 0} + {200\choose 1} +\dots + {200\choose 200}$.
I can get R to calculate this as about $10^{60}$: p <- 200; s <- rep(NA, p + 1); for (i in 0:p){s[i + 1] <- choose(p, i)}; sum(s). This turns out to be equal to $2^p$, where $p$ is the feature count.
That's how many models you have to fit. Assume it takes one Planck time, approx $10^{-44}$ seconds to fit a model. Then you have a run time $\approx 10^{16}$ seconds.
$$
\dfrac{
10^{16}\text{ seconds}
}{
1
}
\times
\dfrac{
1\text{ hour}
}{
3600\text{ seconds}
}
\times
\dfrac{
1\text{ day}
}{
24\text{ hour}
}
\times
\dfrac{
1\text{ year}
}{
366\text{ days}
}
=316231532
\text{ years}
$$
So even assuming the fastest computing time that makes any physical sense, it would take 300-million years. The dinosaurs could have started this and would not be done.
But you don't have a computer with enough parallel processing to calculate each model in one Planck time, and you have $2000$ features, not $200$. Thus, it won't take you 300-million years. It will take you much longer.
But it gets even worse!
You would want to have some sense of how stable those selected features are and if there is a reason to expect those to be the good features to use in general, not just on the particular data. Frank Harrell has recommended bootstrapping the data and applying your feature-selection method each time in order to get a sense of how stable the selection is, and it is often the case the selection methods are not particularly stable, so you may have just waited a trillion-trillion years just to get a result of, "This isn't very effective." Here, he discusses alternatives and refers to his Regression Modeling Strategies textbook. (Yes, your machine learning predictor is, in some sense, a regression, even if it is not a linear regression.)
Thus, what you propose kind of makes sense in a world with unlimited computing power or at least enough computing power to handle a small number of features (25 features results in only about 30-million possible models). However, feature selection steps in general tend to be unstable, which I why I say it is not really valid, even without the computing constraints.
Finally, this does not even consider the possibility of interactions between features or nonlinear functions of the features. Making explicit use of these is less important in, say, neural networks, random forests, and SVMs than in linear or generalized linear models, but it is worth considering that your features might be worthless on their own but useful if you, say, square them.

library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2024)
x <- seq(-5, 5, 0.01)
y <- x^2 + rnorm(length(x))
d <- data.frame(x, y)
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point()


(There are 2^n_features subsets; the sum of those binomial coefficients is equal to this.)

The question is whether it is 'valid', and it is not about feasibility (I imagine that a large enough quantum computer or analog computer might actually be helpful here to reduce the time drastically). In the example 20 features are and the considerationnis the comparison of the best subset of 8 versus the first 8.

There are some excellent comments here already. The following is a quote I bookmarked from Ewout Steyerberg's book relevant to the topic:

If some of the 20 variables are true predictors, they will sometimes have a relatively small and sometimes a relatively large effect. If we only include a predictor when it has a relatively large effect in our model, we are overestimating the effect of such a predictor. This phenomenon is referred to as testimation bias: because we test first, the effect estimate is biased. Testimation bias is related to phenomena such as “Winner’s curse” and regression to the mean.

Some excellent resources on the topic are:

Sauerbrei, W., Perperoglou, A., Schmid, M., Abrahamowicz, M., Becher, H., Binder, H., Dunkler, D., Harrell, F. E., Royston, P., & Heinze, G. (2020). State of the art in selection of variables and functional forms in multivariable analysis—outstanding issues. Diagnostic and Prognostic Research, 4(1)

Steyerberg, E. W. (2008). Clinical prediction models: A practical approach to development, validation, and updating. Springer

Frank E. Harrell, J. (2015). Regression modeling strategies: With applications to linear models, logistic and ordinal regression, and survival analysis. Springer

Heinze, G., Wallisch, C., & Dunkler, D. (2018). Variable selection - A review and recommendations for the practicing statistician. Biometrical Journal, 60(3), 431-449

Kuhn, M., & Johnson, K. (2019). Feature engineering and selection: A practical approach for predictive models. CRC Press.


Keep in mind that sometimes guidance from one field appears in contrast with another (statistical vs. machine learning camps). Often, this is motivated by different goals, although it needs not be so.

Thanks for the references.


My question is whether this is a valid approach or if I am introducing bias, overfitting, etc., and if so, how to compensate for that.


would it maybe make more sense to use PCA to create 5-10 components instead of using features directly?

Those PCA components rely on all of the features and do not reduce the number of features that are being used.
What is your point behind reducing the number of features?

If you do not realy need to reduce the features for some external reasons...
(like reducing the costs of some application by reducing the amount of features that need to be sampled and processed, or for research on potential theories about the features)

... then you are doing it to reduce overfitting?


In that latter case, reducing overfitting, you can think of incorporating some other way of regularisation in your machine learning problem (e.g ridge regression or elastic net)
In a way the leave one out cross validation that you perform can also be seen as some sort of regularizing penalty term. Namely, it is a transformation of the residuals (and the sum of squared residuals) with a factor including the leverage, and it will penalize the more flexible models that are related to a larger leverage of the data points on the estimate (see Proof of LOOCV formula). However, it will only be a penalty term based on the model matrix (in general it penalizes higher rank regression matrices related to larger leverage), and the estimation of the coefficients is not regularized (there is no shrinking).

Thanks for your time. I've added to the end of my original question.

In the ideal case, the goal of feature selection is to find the best possible subset of features with the highest out-of-distribution (test data) accuracy. Assuming that you can estimate out-of-distribution accuracy, checking all possible subsets gives you the optimal solution, though, it is computationally inefficient, and in most cases infeasible. One can use proper validation mechanisms (k-fold cross validation, leave-one-out, or simply separating training and validation data) to estimate the out-of-distribution accuracy. Given that, there are $2^d$ possible combinations of features to find the best subset with the highest accuracy. If for your specific application, you can brute-force all combinations (or if $k$, the number of desired features is given all choices of $k$ from $d$ features), that is the best possible solution. If you have computational limitations,  you can use different heuristics to estimate the feature selection problem. Using Lasso Regression, Backward of Forward (step-wise) methods, and Tree-based are a few options you can explore.

You have 1000 samples and you want to test 264,000 hypothesis.
Leave subject out is good, but it doesn't save you.
Because you are optimizing over this.
This is why many split their dataset into 3 sets, train, dev, test
keeping a test set where you only test a handfull of times for accurate assement.
If you only want the best model, your cross validation sounds ok. But if you want to not only find the model but also have some kind of clue as to how good it is. you need something extra.
For example you could do a single split, putting say 10 subjects aside and doing your cross validated optimization on only 40 subjects.
I also suspect leave subject out is excessive, and you could get similar results much faster by doing grouped-k-fold with 5-10 folds.
You can do k-fold on top of k-fold but that gets expensive, hence the suggestion for combining a single split with k fold.
