Model performs well on train and cross-validation sets but inaccurate in the test set. How to solve?
I've been working on a CNN binary classification model, and the model performs pretty good in both the training set, and the cross-validation set as well (both practically 1.0 acc). However, I also hold a distinct testing set that I use to set my models at the very end.
I do this because I use hyper-parameter tuning based on the cross-validation accuracy. I believe this might cause a potential for the model architecture to overfit according to the cv set.
How can I ensure that after hyper-parameter tuning, that my model will perform well on the test set, which is neither used during weight training nor the hp tuning?
I'll include an image of the model results here (the very bottom line is the accuracy on the test set):


A frequent explanation is that there was leakage in the cross-validation step.  An example would be using the whole training sample for feature selection (note: feature selection is seldom a good idea in general) but then only cross-validating parameter estimation and not repeating the feature selection afresh for each resample.

My thought process was that just like how we're using cross-validation to avoid overfit in the training set, the model might overfit  to the validation accuracy during hyper-parameter optimization. Because I am tuning hyper-parameters according to the cv set, that might become the new overfitting issue. Then would it be fair to say that the way to overcome this is to ensure we're taking random samples from cross-validation set and build many different architectures, and choose the one best performing on test set?

Note that accuracy is often a very problematic KPI.

As Stephan suggests (+1), over-fitting in cross validation is absolutely a thing.  Mrs Marsupial and I wrote a paper about this in the context of kernel machines, which you may find useful G. C. Cawley and N. L. C. Talbot, Over-fitting in model selection and subsequent selection bias in performance evaluation, JMLR, 2010., vol. 11, pp. 2079-2107, July 2010. https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf I'd also second Frank's good advice (example here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27750/feature-selection-and-cross-validation/27751#27751).

Optimisation is the root of all (almost) evil in statistics - whenever you optimise a criterion based on a finite sample of data you run the risk of over-fitting it.  The smaller the dataset, and the harder you try to optimise it (e.g. more architectural choices), the greater that risk will be.

First off, "overfitting to the out-of-bag set in cross-validation" is absolutely a thing. If you run enough different models through your CV pipeline, and especially if these models are highly variable, then the chance of your best performing model just being in the lead because of random variation is high.
Various forms of data leakage, as Frank Harrell notes, can also be an issue. However, this question is orthogonal to overfitting to the OOB set: you can have both, or either (or neither). Other things that might come into play could be shifts in the data between your sets, or shifts in the data generating process, and so forth.
Unfortunately, there is no surefire way to avoid overfitting to the OOB set. You suggest

taking random samples from cross-validation set and build many different architectures, and choose the one best performing on test set

But note what is happening at the very last step, "choose the one best performing on test set": this is not a test set any more, this is now simply another validation set. Your final-final model is now not only tested on the "test set", but it is selected based on it. And now the exact same issue of overfitting to the OOB/test set arises again. If you ran a million models through the CV, kept the 1,000 top performers in the CV, applied them all to the test set and finally keep the one that works best here, you again have no guarantee that it will be the best at generalizing to yet new unseen data, because one model always necessarily wins. You may be stacking overfitting on top of overfitting.
Note that I am not saying this will not work at all. Your proposed approach will usually improve matters. Whether it does so depends mostly on how much data you have: if you only have 100 data points, use 80 in CV and 20 in testing, but run that full million of models, you will likely be overfitting. If it is the other way around - 100 models, a million data points - you are in a much better situation. And of course "getting more data" is always a good idea.

+1 you will also see over fitting on the validation set when using automl: the internal cross validation metrics (in the training loop to choose good hyperpatameters) are much better than the final test set. So be aware to base any decision on only "somewhat" held out examples. You will have too optimistic performance metrics on the validation set which is used for hyperparamerer tuning. This is why you gave train, validation and test set! Only the test set result is more or less reliable. If you need you can resample these 3 sets and obtain a distribution of test set performances
